# How to display a div when click a button/ tab (3 vertical column)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/6/ but with first column contain the tabs align vertical and second the same and the last column for content, all need to be vertical. So when I will click one Tab1 from column 1 to open coulmn 2 with a list of tabs and when I click on tab1 from column 2 to open a div.
I made a sketch how I need it: [shetch.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwOE.png) I tried to make it by myself but i make every time something wrong, the result is all the time without succes. If anyone can help me I will be very grateful! Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var tab = $('.faq-row-handle > a'),
  tabContent = $('.faq-row-content'),
  tabParent = $('.faq-row');
 
  if(tab.length){
  
   tab.off('click').on('click', function(){
    
    var ele = $(this),
     currContent = $('#'+ele.attr('rel'));
    
     if(!ele.hasClass('open')){
     
      tabParent.stop(true, true).animate({
       height:'0px'
       
      },function() {
       tabContent.removeClass('open');
       currContent.addClass('open');
       tab.removeClass('open');
       ele.addClass('open');
       
       tabParent.stop(true, true).animate({
        height:currContent.height()+'px'
       }); 
        
      });
   
     }  
  
   });
 
   $('.faq-row-handle > a:eq(0)').click();
 }

});
```

```css
.clear{
    clear:both; 
    display:block; 
    height:0; 
    width:auto;
}

.faq-row-container{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

.faq-row {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.faq-row-handle {
    border:#ccc 1px solid; 
    border-bottom:none;
}

.faq-row-handle > a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: #191919;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 7px 30px 7px 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    float:left;
     border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.faq-row-handle a.open{
   color:green;
}

.faq-row-content {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.faq-row-content.open{
    display:block;
}

.faq-row-content p {
    padding: 0 14px 10px 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-row-container">
    
    <div class="faq-row-handle">
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item1">1. item</a>  
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item2">2. item</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item3">3. item</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item4">4. item</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item5">5. item</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" rel="item6">6. item</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-row">
        
        <div id="item1" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="item2" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="item3" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="item4" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="item5" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>5 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.</p>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="item6" class="faq-row-content">
            <p>6 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would probably try CSS Grid.  Read [All 3 pages of CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) at w3schools.  Also, for more info on grid alignment, [check out this page](https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/center-and-align-items-in-css-grid/), especially item #6 for individual grid-item alignment.

Comment: The code above it's fine already, just I dont get how to customize it to look like the sketch I want and to make one more column. If anyone can help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: As I said, take a look at using CSS Grid to get it to look like the sketch.  All the info you need is in those links. Don't expect people to write the code for you.  If you can't figure it out, then post what you have tried.

Comment: I think you are looking for something [like this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/kan8vh04/1/)

Comment: Similar with that but I need something like.. when click item 1, item 2 or item 3 to show item 4, item 5, item 6 and when i click item 4, item 5 or item 6 to show content of item 4, item 5 or item 6. That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult.  You will need to modify the jquery.  Do some research, make some attempts at writing the code yourself then post here if you still fail.

Comment: I made this https://jsfiddle.net/xhope23b/ I tried to edit the jQuery and add some divs but I don't get how to edit it to show another column. So right now when I click on a button from column 1, are showing a column 2, I don't get how to click on a button from column 2 to open a column 3 with a text. I tried to dublicate the jQuery and divs but doesn't works

Comment: Anyone can help? I can pay if is necessary. I'm stucked to that..